# Bitbucket To Google app engine Deployment Failed ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) INVALID_ARGUMENT: WEB-INF/appengine-web.xml is required for this runtime

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, bitbucket

I would like to deploy BitBucket to Google App Engine, I have done the all configuartion using [bitbucket-cloud/docs/deploy-to-google-cloud/](https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/deploy-to-google-cloud/) this link. I have done bitbucket-pipelines.yml as follows :-

```
  image: atlassian/default-image:2

pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        script:
          - pipe: atlassian/google-app-engine-deploy:0.7.3
            variables:
              KEY_FILE: $KEY_FILE
              PROJECT: 'project_id'
              DEPLOYABLES: 'SlickErp/war/WEB-INF/appengine-web.xml'
              VERSION: '11'
              #BUCKET: 'gs://my-bucket'
              IMAGE: 'gcr.io/my/image'
              PROMOTE: 'true'
              STOP_PREVIOUS_VERSION: 'true'
              #EXTRA_ARGS: '--logging=debug'
```

and Also configured the PROJECT and KEY_FILE in the Repository variables.
When I run the my pipeline deploy to google app engine getting following issue :-

```
Digest: sha256:ba2b161552a88f64dc0d3a5efe391aff52b06e16ca9b3933d0f0279869580465
Status: Downloaded newer image for bitbucketpipelines/google-app-engine-deploy:0.7.3
INFO: Setting up environment.
echo "${KEY_FILE}" | base64 -d >> /tmp/key-file.json
gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file /tmp/key-file.json --quiet --verbosity=warning
Activated service account credentials for: [account@appspot.gserviceaccount.com]
gcloud config set project project_id --quiet --verbosity=warning
Updated property [core/project].
WARNING: You do not appear to have access to project [project_id] or it does not exist.
INFO: Starting deployment to GCP app engine...
gcloud app --quiet deploy SlickErp/war/WEB-INF/appengine-web.xml --version=11 --image-url gcr.io/my/image --promote --stop-previous-version --verbosity=warning
Services to deploy:
descriptor:      [/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/SlickErp/war/WEB-INF/appengine-web.xml]
source:          [/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/SlickErp/war]
target project:  [project_id]
target service:  [default]
target version:  [11]
target url:      [https://project_id.an.r.appspot.com]
Beginning deployment of service [default]...
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) INVALID_ARGUMENT: WEB-INF/appengine-web.xml is required for this runtime.
✖ Deployment failed.
```

what is the issue i am getting below error :-

```
  ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) INVALID_ARGUMENT: WEB-INF/appengine-web.xml is required for this runtime.
    ✖ Deployment failed.
```

Any help?
Thank You in advance

Comment: In the tutorial you shared it mentions to use a `app.yaml` file and not `appengine-web.xml`. Also, I think you're deploying a JAVA app and the file `appengine-web.xml` was deprecated for JAVA 8.

Answer (score 0):

The gcloud deploy is failing to find the appengine-web.xml file, verify that you're writing the correct path on your yml file.

Comment: Thank you for response my appengine-web.xml file path is SlickErp/war/WEB-INF/appengine-web.xml. I have given the same path in DEPLOYABLES variables in the script.